# Относительное расположение элементов ScrollArea pyqt5

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, pyqt, layout

1. Мне нужен некоторый столбец кнопок, высотой, к примеру, 2000 пикселей, и чтобы этот столбец находился в ScrollArea, чтобы его можно было листать. Существуют ли какие то удобные способы редактирования этого столбца, так как он не помещается в экран и я могу редактировать только его часть?
2. Возможно ли сделать элементы адаптируемыми к размерам окна без жесткой сетки layout'a? У меня есть окно с элементами и мне нужно, чтобы при изменении размеров окна они не выходили за его пределы, а чтобы они адаптировались (изменяли свой размер). Это возможно сделать с помощью layout'a, но там жесткая сетка, а мои элементы расположены произвольно.

В примере снизу есть кнопки 4,5,6 , таких кнопок должно быть более 40, необходимо чтобы их можно было скроллить, но я не могу добавить больше 20 кнопок, потому что больше не помещается в экран. Также мне необходимо, чтобы все элементы окна адаптировались к его размерам, но если я использую layout, то все элементы выстраиваются в сетку, что мне не нужно

```py
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(900, 710)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.button1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.button1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 30, 131, 51))
        self.button1.setObjectName("button1")
        self.text1 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.text1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(150, 120, 111, 41))
        self.text1.setObjectName("text1")
        self.text2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.text2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(150, 160, 111, 41))
        self.text2.setObjectName("text2")
        self.button2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.button2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(280, 90, 131, 121))
        self.button2.setObjectName("button2")
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(90, 230, 441, 20))
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.button3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.button3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(200, 310, 131, 31))
        self.button3.setObjectName("button3")
        self.button4 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.button4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(200, 360, 131, 31))
        self.button4.setObjectName("button4")
        self.button5 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.button5.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(200, 410, 131, 31))
        self.button5.setObjectName("button5")
        self.button6 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.button6.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(200, 460, 131, 31))
        self.button6.setObjectName("button6")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 900, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.button1.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "1"))
        self.text1.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "text1"))
        self.text2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "text2"))
        self.button2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "2"))
        self.button3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "3"))
        self.button4.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "4"))
        self.button5.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "5"))
        self.button6.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "6"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Заранее спасибо за ответы

Comment: Опубликуйте пожалуйста ваш пример для демонстрации проблем описанных выше.

Comment: Я не буду минусовать Ваш вопрос, но Вы все гляньте на правила. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask и отредактируйте свое сообщение, убрав лирику, разбив Ваше сообщение на отдельные вопросы и придав им конкретности.

Comment: @S.Nick добавил пример

Answer (score 0):

У меня, к сожалению, нет практического опыта, чтобы нарисовать то что вы хотите в Qt Designer.
Я убрал с вашего примера `button3 - button6` и создал `class Widget`, 
в котором будет некоторый столбец кнопок  в ScrollArea.

Управление расположением с помощью классов Layout является более гибким и практичным. 
Вот один из вариантов того, что вы хотите. Попробуйте отрегулировать размеры как вам нравится.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore    import *                           
from PyQt5.QtGui     import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import * 

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(700, 510)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")

        self.button1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.button1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 30, 131, 51))
        self.button1.setObjectName("button1")
        self.text1 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.text1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(150, 120, 111, 41))
        self.text1.setObjectName("text1")
        self.text2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.text2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(150, 160, 111, 41))
        self.text2.setObjectName("text2")
        self.button2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.button2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(280, 90, 131, 121))
        self.button2.setObjectName("button2")
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(90, 230, 441, 20))
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        """
        self.button3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.button3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(200, 310, 131, 31))
        self.button3.setObjectName("button3")
        self.button4 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.button4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(200, 360, 131, 31))
        self.button4.setObjectName("button4")
        self.button5 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.button5.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(200, 410, 131, 31))
        self.button5.setObjectName("button5")
        self.button6 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.button6.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(200, 460, 131, 31))
        self.button6.setObjectName("button6")
        """
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 900, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.button1.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "1"))
        self.text1.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "text1"))
        self.text2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "text2"))
        self.button2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "2"))
        """
        self.button3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "3"))
        self.button4.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "4"))
        self.button5.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "5"))
        self.button6.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "6"))
        """


class Widget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Widget, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setMinimumSize(140, 170)
# или так       
#        self.setFixedSize(140, 170)

        widget = QWidget()
        layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        for _ in range(40):
            btn = QPushButton("test {}".format(_))
            layout.addWidget(btn)
        widget.setLayout(layout)

        scroll = QScrollArea()
        scroll.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOn)
        scroll.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        scroll.setWidgetResizable(True)
        scroll.setWidget(widget)

        vLayout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        vLayout.addWidget(scroll)
        self.setLayout(vLayout)


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):                         
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.widget = Widget(self.centralwidget)

        self.grid = QGridLayout(self.centralwidget) 

        self.button1.setMinimumSize(120, 50)
        self.grid.addWidget(self.button1, 0, 0, Qt.AlignLeft) 

        self.grid.addWidget(self.text1, 2, 1)
        self.grid.addWidget(self.text2, 3, 1)

        self.button2.setMinimumSize(120, 120)
        self.button2.setMaximumWidth(240)
        self.grid.addWidget(self.button2, 2, 3, 2, 2) 

        self.grid.addWidget(self.lineEdit, 4, 0, 1, 12) 
        self.grid.addWidget(self.widget, 5, 3) 



if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = MainWindow()  # QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
#    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
#    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

**Update**

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore    import *                           
from PyQt5.QtGui     import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import * 

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(800, 600)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.widget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.widget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 20, 621, 521))
        self.widget.setObjectName("widget")

        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.gridLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        self.button1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.widget)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.button1.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.button1.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.button1.setObjectName("button1")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.button1, 0, 0, 1, 2)

        spacerItem = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(428, 20, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        self.gridLayout.addItem(spacerItem, 0, 2, 1, 4)

        self.horizontalLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout.setObjectName("horizontalLayout")
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.widget)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.label)
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.widget)
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.label_2)
        self.horizontalLayout.addLayout(self.verticalLayout)

        self.button2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.widget)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)  
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.button2.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.button2.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.button2.setBaseSize(QtCore.QSize(120, 120))
        self.button2.setObjectName("button2")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.button2)

        self.gridLayout.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout, 1, 1, 1, 4)

        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.widget)
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit, 2, 1, 1, 4)

        self.widget1 = Widget(self.widget)
        self.widget1.setObjectName("widget1")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.widget1, 3, 2, 1, 2)

        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 800, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.button1.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "1"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "TextLabel 1"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "TextLabel 2"))
        self.button2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "2"))


class Widget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Widget, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setMaximumHeight(170)

        widget = QWidget()
        layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        for _ in range(40):
            btn = QPushButton("{} test".format(_))
            layout.addWidget(btn)
        widget.setLayout(layout)

        scroll = QScrollArea()
        scroll.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOn)
        scroll.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        scroll.setWidgetResizable(True)
        scroll.setWidget(widget)

        vLayout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        vLayout.addWidget(scroll)
        self.setLayout(vLayout)


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):                         
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyle("Fusion")
    MainWindow = MainWindow()  
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Это никак не решает мою проблему. Мне нужно, чтобы кнопки адаптировались к размерам окна, но они не увеличиваются при увеличении размеров окна, они просто не дают окну принять размер меньше установленного

Comment: Значит я не понял вашу проблему. Вы можете нарисовать два изображения?  1. стартовое и 2. после изменения размера.

Comment: @ИгорьКудашев я добавил новый пример, попробуйте.